# HTML <Select> chosen.js clipped from table row

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I have a  filled with items and styled with [chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/):

```
<select class="chosen-select" id="gsch" name="gsch" required> 
  <option> ... </option>
</select>
```

My problem is that this select is inside a table, and the combobox displayed by chosen is truncated because its height exceeds the row's.

Is there a way to tell chosen to overlap the row?

Comment: Can you post an example using something like jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is a css issue.
The following code snippet from [issues](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86) solves it.

```
$(".chzn-select").on("liszt:showing_dropdown", function () {
$(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "visible");
});
$(".chzn-select").on("liszt:hiding_dropdown", function () {
$(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "");
});
```